# Vertices seem to be stuck when sculpting

Tags: modeling, sculpting

I'm working on a model, and I can move vertices in edit mode just fine but once I go into sculpting there are certain vertices that refuse to budge the way they should.

This is how it looks unedited.

[image]

But then as soon as I go into sculpt mode and try to drag it, stuff like this happens.

[image]

I tried recalculating the normals because that seems to be the obvious solution but it didn't change anything.